# Ignore global options in local tikz environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzposter

Using the package `fancytikzposter` creates a bunch of tikz styles in order to draw the blocks on the poster. However, when now using a `tikzpicture` environment myself, all these styles 'drip into' the customized tikz picture. In particular, this destroys tikz pictures which work with a plain LaTeX + TikZ installation.

'MWE':

```
% either use documentclass standalone OR
% the fancytikzposter template inside documentclass a0poster
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (25:4) {A};
  \node at (155:4) {B};
  \node at (270:2) {C};

  \draw[-implies, double distance=0.25cm]
  (160:3) -- (230:1.65);

  \draw[implies-, double distance=0.25cm]
  (165:4) -- (220:2.5);

  \draw [-implies, double distance=0.25cm]
  (-2, 1.7) -- (2, 1.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

generates the correct figure in a standalone class:

[image: TikZ code executed in a standalone]

but fails to produce anything useful when inside a `fancytikzposter` inside a `blocknode` (to replicate this, use the fancytikzposter template, a proper MWE would blow up this post):

[image: TikZ code execute in a fancytikzposter]

Observe, that the nodes look like little block nodes themselves, which leads to the suspicion that the global settings interfere with the drawing. Having looked into the source of `fancytikzposter`, it seems that the package only defines certain names as styles (e.g. `frame`, `innerframe` etc), but somehow there must be a *default style*.

I've tried:

- to enclose the entire drawing code in a `scope` environment with an empty style,
- to define `\tikzset{mystyle={}}` and then `\draw[mystyle]` everything,

but neither has yielded any results.

**How can I draw a *normal, default* tikzpicture, ignoring existing global styles and options?**

PS: Of course, one could draw the pictures in a standalone and then `\includegraphics` them, but it would be much nicer to draw on the poster directly.

Comment: Could you post the code of the example leading to the second screenshot? (To the first approximation, I would just try `\node[draw=none,fill=white,rectangle,anchor=center] at (25:4) {A};`)

Comment: Use the `tikzposter` class instead.

Comment: You could create the tikzpicture using document class standalone and import the PDF into the posster.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you did not really disclose the code that leads to the problematic output. Nevertheless, there is a rather simple trick that allows you to effectively nest `tikzpicture`s: put them into a `\savebox` that is created outside the ambient `tikzpicture`, and then use it within the node or whatever. Notice that in the `tikzposter` calls, which superseded the `fancytikzposter` style, this is no longer necessary. (Big thanks to Torbørn T. for pointing this out!), but as you seem to still use the `fancytikzposter` style, this trick might be useful. And it might be useful in other occasions.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\newsavebox{\mypic}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\sbox\mypic{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (25:4) {A};
  \node at (155:4) {B};
  \node at (270:2) {C};

  \draw[-implies, double distance=0.25cm]
  (160:3) -- (230:1.65);

  \draw[implies-, double distance=0.25cm]
  (165:4) -- (220:2.5);

  \draw [-implies, double distance=0.25cm]
  (-2, 1.7) -- (2, 1.7);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\block{Some title}{\usebox\mypic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `tikzposter` actually boxes the content of `\block`s, so you don't have to do it manually when using that class. (You'll see that adding the `tikzpicture` directly to the `\block` works fine.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the fancytikzposter has been replaced by tikzposter.

The problem you face comes from the wat the nodes are drawn. All contents of a blocknode is drawn using the multipart package and therefore has the same layout as the "master" node. In fact, every block is made up of title blocks and many more.

The solution that has been mentioned by marmot, using a savebox is perhaps the easiest way out.